# How to convert UTC to human readable format when uploading CSV files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

How to convert UTC format to human readable format when uploading CSV files.

Below is my Model & Controller, there are all is OK, CSV files uploading nicely.

I need convert UTC to Human readable format while uploading CSV files, is this possible on Ruby on Rails? I don't know even I don't have any idea how to do this.

Model

```
def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        Product.create! row.to_hash
    end
end
```

Controller

```
def import
    Product.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

CSV File

```
-----------------------------
| name |      date_utc     |
-----------------------------
| John | 13123193563116372 |
```

DB Table

```
--------------------------------------
| id | name | date_utc | created_at |
--------------------------------------
|    |      |          |            |
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: `Time.at(13123193563116372).utc.to_datetime` => `Thu, 14 Jun 417827 09:18:36 +0000` which is kind'a insane. Are you sure you have correct data in CSV? :)

Comment: I would argue that `UTC` a time zone, not a representation format. Therefore the number is meaningless in the context of `UTC`. It might be a timestamp, but it is way to big to be a normal unix timestamp. Please explain what kind of timestamp that example number is and what the expected output might look like.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Actually this is send me my client & he taken from his browser logs.

Comment: @spickermann I need human readable format from this number, it is timestamps, saved from browser logs

Comment: How do you generate that timestamp in your browser logs?

Comment: @spickermann send me from others and told me this to create human readable

Comment: Than they have to tell you how the number is create, how it is designed and calculated.

Comment: lastone is you Product table?

Comment: Thanks @spickermann,  I will tell  him for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own solution

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
     p_hash = Product.new
     p_hash.name = row[0]
     p_hash.date_utc = Time.at(row[1].to_i).strftime("%B %e, %Y at %I:%M :%S %p")
     p_hash.save
  end
end
```

I have considered timestamp number length.

Thanks for participating everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This may be help you:

```
 CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row| 
   product = Product.new
   product.name = row[0]
   product.date_utc = Time.at(row[1])
   product.save
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got after stripping the last digit (2) and assuming a timestamp including microseconds:

```
Time.at(1312319356311637 / (1000 * 1000)).utc.to_datetime
# => 2011-08-02T21:09:16+00:00
```

Then your CSV parsing would look like this:

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
  # Assuming it is a 17 digit number, we divide by 10 to remove the last digit.
  parsed_time = Time.at(row[1] / (10 * 1000000)).utc.to_datetime
  Product.create!(name: row[0], date_utc: parsed_time)
end
```

Note that this solution will only work if the `date_utc` is 17 digits long. And you will lose the original precision.
I would highly recommend to cross-check with the people you get your data from if this assumption is correct.